# Rails devise authentication, external app requesting blocked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a rails app that uses devise authentication system. There is another external rails app which requests this app but because of the code below in application_controller, it can't pass through.

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

What is the best way/design to let the application get authenticated correctly and get the response without a problem.

Any hint is appreciated

Comment: Can you give us a more concrete example? Why would you want to authenticate the user on the app by itself but then then not want to when accessing the app from an external application?

Comment: Rephrasing the question like this might give you a hint? what is the standard approach to request a rails app which uses devise from another app.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use token authentication to allow the app to pass a secret token via a url query parameter or use [HTTP Basic Authentication](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Basic+Authentication).

https://github.com/baschtl/devise-token_authenticatable

You would need to create a user account and generate a token for it and use that token for every request that your app makes by either including `?tolen_param_name=SECRET` or use Http basic authentication with the user's username and password.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication

Note that it's safer to enable ssl over the http connection to encrypt the password or secret.